# Unable to connect local database server from visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Everything was working fine before. but after couple of days when i start working today on vs 10, i tried to connect to database and got the following error.. here is the image describing whole situation while creating a new database[image]

Comment: Can you connect from Management Studio or another application?
Is the server started in Control panel/Services?

Comment: sorry but i didn't get what you mean by 'Is the server started in Control panel/Services'

Comment: no..whenever i try to connect i got error 26 or 40

Comment: Got this error when i started 'SQL Express Windows could not start the SQL Server on Local Computer Error Code 3417'

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that you can't connect to your local server. Since it's local, you can rule out connectivity issues, so it's likely that the SQL service isn't running. Pull up your services dialog (Computer Management -> Services) and scroll down to "SQL Server". You should see the service's state as not running. Right click on it and hit "start". You should be good to go from there.

Comment: when i was starting service i got a new error                             'windows could not start sql server service on local computer'  for this i went to event viewer...now what is next step ?

Comment: The event viewer should have something more specific. Check the system and application logs.